# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint. Is My Entity Framework Configuration good for desired behaviour?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

While creating new DbSeries I'm getting an exception:

> Inner Exception 1:
>   UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Inner Exception 2:
>   SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.SimpleLines_dbo.DropPhotos_SimpleLineId". The conflict occurred in database "DDROPDATABASE_c40e1078b22e4eebae917b2f22aafcba", table "dbo.DropPhotos", column 'DropPhotoId'.

Please check my EF configuration. I'm not really experienced. My desired behaviour is:

- There is DbUser. Upon creation he don't have any DbSeries, but he could add some of them later. One DbUser could have multiple DbSeries.
- Upon creation DbSeries don't have any DbDropPhoto's and don't have any ReferencePhoto. One DbReferencePhoto could be add to DbSeries. Multiple DbDropPhotos could be added to one DbSeries. When DbSeries is deleted all DbDropPhotos and DbReferencePhoto related to it must be deleted and DbUser shouldn't be deleted.
- Single DbDropPhotos have single Drop which is must be created upon DbDropPhoto creation and must be deleted if DbDropPhoto is deleted or if the Series, which contains it parent DbDropPhoto is deleted. DbDropPhoto contains two DbSimpleLine's. Upon creation of DbDropPhoto those DbSimpleLine is not added and could be added later. Upon deletion of parent DbDropPhoto or parent Series of this DbDropPhoto those two DbSimpleLines must be deleted.
- DbReferencePhoto containse DbSimpleLine. DbSimpleLine is not created with creation of DbReferencePhoto and could be added later. Updon Deletion of DbReferencePhoto or deletion of it parent DbSeries DbSimpleLine must be deleted.

Here is my entity configuration:

```
public class DbUser
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public List<DbSeries> UserSeries { get; set; }
}

public class DbSeries
{
    [Key]
    public Guid SeriesId { get; set; }

    public List<DbDropPhoto> DropPhotosSeries { get; set; }
    public virtual DbReferencePhoto ReferencePhotoForSeries { get; set; }

    public Guid CurrentUserId { get; set; }
    public DbUser CurrentUser { get; set; }
}

public class DbReferencePhoto
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ReferencePhotoId { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSimpleLine SimpleLine { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSeries Series { get; set; }
}

public class DbDropPhoto
{
    [Key]
    public Guid DropPhotoId { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSimpleLine SimpleHorizontalLine { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSimpleLine SimpleVerticalLine { get; set; }

    public virtual DbDrop Drop { get; set; }

    public Guid CurrentSeriesId { get; set; }
    public DbSeries CurrentSeries { get; set; }
}

public class DbDrop
{
    [Key]
    public Guid DropId { get; set; }

    public virtual DbDropPhoto DropPhoto { get; set; }
}

public class DbSimpleLine
{
    [Key]
    public Guid SimpleLineId { get; set; }

    public virtual DbReferencePhoto ReferencePhoto { get; set; }
    public virtual DbDropPhoto DropPhotoHorizontalLine { get; set; }
    public virtual DbDropPhoto DropPhotoVerticalLine { get; set; }
}
```

and my fluent api configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<DbUser>()
        .HasMany(s => s.UserSeries)
        .WithRequired(g => g.CurrentUser)
        .HasForeignKey(s => s.CurrentUserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<DbSeries>()
        .HasMany(s => s.DropPhotosSeries)
        .WithRequired(g => g.CurrentSeries)
        .HasForeignKey(s => s.CurrentSeriesId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete();

    modelBuilder.Entity<DbSeries>()
        .HasRequired(s => s.ReferencePhotoForSeries)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal(ad => ad.Series);

    modelBuilder.Entity<DbDropPhoto>()
        .HasRequired(s => s.Drop)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal(ad => ad.DropPhoto);

    modelBuilder.Entity<DbDropPhoto>()
        .HasRequired(s => s.SimpleHorizontalLine)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal(ad => ad.DropPhotoHorizontalLine);

    modelBuilder.Entity<DbDropPhoto>()
        .HasRequired(s => s.SimpleVerticalLine)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal(ad => ad.DropPhotoVerticalLine);

    modelBuilder.Entity<DbReferencePhoto>()
        .HasRequired(s => s.SimpleLine)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal(ad => ad.ReferencePhoto);
}
```

Maybe one SimpleLineId is not enough and I need to create more keys for it?

```
public virtual DbReferencePhoto ReferencePhoto { get; set; }
public virtual DbDropPhoto DropPhotoHorizontalLine { get; set; }
public virtual DbDropPhoto DropPhotoVerticalLine { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly verify whether `DbSeries` has records or not before inserting records into `DbDropPhoto`.

The issue occurs when the `DbSeries` record is empty and you are trying to insert records in `DbDropPhoto`.

First you have to insert data into `DbSeries` table, containing the primary key, before you insert data into the `DbDropPhoto` table containing the foreign key.

Comment: should i also add more keys for DbSimpleLine? Or one is enough?

Comment: one key is enough.